# Joomla: Raw Output With Title And Description Possible?

Tags: joomla1.7

I have a simple question. Is it possible to set a Title and a Description when displaying RAW output? (format=raw)

Currently I'm getting empty <head> tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: no.

Raw output only displays the component output of a page, nothing else.

Try using this instead `tmpl=component`